# How to find the MGF of the difference of 2 random variables

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, expected-value, moment-generating-function

Let $X\sim N(12,4)$ and $Y \sim N(3,1)$

Let $Z = X - Y$

Find the Moment Generating Function of $Z$.

I tried finding the expected value of $e$ to the power of $tz$, but this isn't possible to separate in the expected value function. I know how to use find the MGF when it is a sum of 2 random variables, but what is the technique when it is a difference like this?

Comment: Use $-Y \sim N(-3,1)$ and add.

Comment: Why is the variance not also negative?

Comment: There's no such thing as a negative variance.  Negating a variable doesn't change the amount it varies around its mean, so the variance remains the same.

Comment: @whuber  Nowhere does the OP say that the random variables are jointly normal

Comment: @Dilip That is true and well worth remembering.  But that point has been made here on CV *ad nauseam,* so it would suffice for a respondent to make the assumption explicit and move on.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from @whuber's comment, $-Y$ has normal distribution with mean $-3$ and variance $1$. So $Z = X - Y = X + (-Y)$ has normal distribution with mean $12-3=9$ and variance $4+1=5$. The moment generating function of a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ is $e^{\mu t + \sigma^2 t^2/2}$, and so the moment generating function of $Z$ is
$$
e^{9t + \frac52 t^2}.
$$